# Fixed flutter version on pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

When you create a flutter project it creates a `pubspec.yaml` with:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

1. Why is this version not fixed? like `sdk: 1.17.5`
2. How can I define it to have only one flutter and dart version supported?

Im worried about this since we can get build problems or runtime issues that are not reproducible because of an internal version change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to set the version fixed for `flutter` and `dart` with the environment block:

```
environment:
  sdk: "2.8.4" # Dart
  flutter: 1.17.5
```

with that the `pubspec.lock` does have the fixed version:

```
sdks:
  dart: "2.8.4"
  flutter: "1.17.5"
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought sdk was referring to flutter, but actually is dart. That is so confusing!

Answer (score 0):

To fix flutter to 3.7.1 version I used this notation:

```
environment:
  flutter: '>=3.7.1 <3.7.2'
```

just setting `flutter: 3.7.1` didn't work for me cause it adds this to `pubspec.lock` file:

```
sdks:
  flutter: ">=3.7.1"
```